# Android Line Chart

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, linechart

I am trying to make a line chart in Android with data from a Firebase Realtime Database.

This is the structure of the database :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olbIA.png)

This is the code :

```
public class TemperaturaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LineChart Temp_linechart;
    ArrayList<Entry> yData;
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener;
    DatabaseReference mPostReference;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_temperatura);
        Temp_linechart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.linechart1);

        mPostReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("dht");
        mPostReference.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                yData = new ArrayList<>();
                float i = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    i = i + 1;
                    String SV = ds.child("temp").getValue().toString();
                    Float SensorValue = Float.parseFloat(SV);
                    yData.add(new Entry(i, SensorValue));
                }
                final LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(yData, "Temp");
                lineDataSet.setLineWidth(4);
                LineData lineData = new LineData(lineDataSet);
                Temp_linechart.clear();
                Temp_linechart.setData(lineData);
                //Temp_linechart.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Temp_linechart.invalidate();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I don't receive any data in my line chart and I don't know why.

Comment: use from some libraries like :

https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the values of `temp` property, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference dhtRef = rootRef.child("sensor").child("dht");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            double temp = ds.child("temp").getValue(Double.class);
            Log.d("TAG", name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
dhtRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in the logcat will be the values of `temp` property:

```
32.7
32.7
32.7
```

I'm not familiar with that Line Chart library, but now having those values, you can do whatever you want with them.

P.S. Always add calls to all nodes that are present in your reference, including the one to `.child("sensor")`.

Comment: How can i plot instead of variable i the current date and time ?

Comment: I cannot see any Timestamp property in any of those nodes. So I'm afraid I didn't understand the question. Besides that, you more likely recommended to post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.